# Javascript unable to read non <input> tags

Tags: javascript

Small problem, with my Javascript code the program is suppose to read with `getElementById`, but I cannot get this to work with my `main` and `<p>` tags the program will only read with an `input` tag (I want to program to read the text on the website).

The program will only say "Undefined" whenever I press the button.
Does anyone know the idea for this issue.

Area in code where Text-To-Speech won't work

```
<main id="text"> This program API is not working </main>
<p id="text"> This is also not read </p>
```

The Supporting button

```
<button type="button" onclick="SoeechModule()" class="btn btn-info" "> Text To Speech </button>
```

The Javascript which works (Other than the aforementioned issue)

```
function SpeechModule(var1)
{
   const TxtToSpeech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    let search = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;

    TxtToSpeech.text = search;
   
    TxtToSpeech.volume = 2;
    TxtToSpeech.rate = 0.5;
    TxtToSpeech.pitch = 2;
   
    TxtToSpeech.voice = voices[4];
   
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(TxtToSpeech);

}
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Use `.innerText` instead of `.value`.

Comment: Gilsdav's answer is correct; also your example has <main id="text> witout a closing "

Comment: @Frazer as much as it’s annoying to look at, that won’t matter. HTML is really fault tolerant

Comment: @Gilsdav Edit, It works, but only if you use it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use innerText for each element. Also you are using `id="text"` multiple times, id is unique and you can fetch only the first item with it if you assign same id to multiple elements. Run the updates code snippet:

```js
function TextToSpeech() {
  const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  //let convert = document.getElementById("text").value;
  speech.text = document.getElementById("text1").innerText;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
  speech.text = document.getElementById("text2").innerText;
  window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}
```

```html
<main id="text1"> This program API is not working
</main>
<p id="text2"> This is also not read
</p>


<button type="button" onclick="TextToSpeech()" class="btn btn-info" "> Text To Speech </button>
```